# Displaying a different name in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have
 in admin.py:

```
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['product', 'dollar_amount']
```

in models.py

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField()
```

I would like to display 'dollar_amount' as 'price'. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Set verbose_name on the dollar_amount field to "price."

**Edit:**

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Price')
```

Comment: Where do I put that? I tried it in admin.py, but it's giving an error.

Comment: See my edit.  you put it in your models.py.

Answer (score 0):

```
in models.py:

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
  product = models.CharField(max_length=256)
  dollar_amount = models.FloatField()

  def price(self):
    return self.dollar_amount

in admin.py:

 class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display=('product','price')
```